# Is there a way to monitor battery usage in real-time in android studio?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, battery, android-profiler

There's an option to check the battery usage history presented [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/battery-historian.html). But is there a way to monitor battery usage in real-time as done in the Android Profiler with CPU, memory and network?

[image: android-profiler]

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about how to check the battery level programmatically, you should take a look at the Android page [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html).

It shows how to register changes on the battery level through the `BatteryManager` broadcast receiver.